# Logging entrance & exit of thousands of method without using AOP in Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, spring-aop

I have tried Spring AOP + log4j but since my intention is to log  method entrance + exit time & some other infos in every existing methods, it impacted the performance a lot, so I had to remove AOP codes and look for alternative solutions. Is there any other way to do this that goes easy on performance? My last resort is to create a tool that scan all codes and adds logging codes in all methods but that will end up in messy codes and become hard to maintain. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your motivation. And what is your expectation if you implement the same with inlined code, how much quicker it will be? Did you do some compare AOP vs. hardcoded logging on sample app? Would logging in service layer only make sense?

Answer (score 1):

As *Betlista* said: If you want to time all method calls in your application and inline the code, do you really think this will be faster? And why would you do that in the first place? Just run a sampling profiler if you want to find bottlenecks.

But as for avoiding the undeniable overhead caused by Spring AOP's dynamic proxies and get performance similar to inlining all statements, I recommend using [AspectJ via LTW (load-time weaving)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj). If you use CTW (compile-time weaving) via AspectJ Maven plugin you can even get rid of the LTW performance penalty during application start-up.

Don't forget what the medical doctors say: The dose is what makes the difference between healing medicine and poison. So even with AspectJ only log/time what you need and what gives you the insights you need, not blindly everything.